# readPreference not working in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm using the following snippet to connect to MongoDB via Mongoose

```
var conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://user:pass@IP:port/testDB',
{
    auth: {authdb: "admin"},
    server: {
        readPreference: "secondary",
        strategy: "ping"
    },
    "db": {
        "readPreference": "secondary",
        "read_preference" : "secondary"
    },
    replset: {
        rs_name : "rs1",
        readPreference: 'secondary'
    }
}
);
```

But `readPreference` doesn't seem to work.

Note:  When I query directly from secondary through the Mongo shell, the data does not exist. Only in primary data is available. But through Mongoose, data comes out.

Can someone help or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
var schema = new Schema({..}, { read: 'secondary' });
```

From the connection, you could set

```
replset: { strategy: 'ping', read: 'secondary' }
```

After trial and error, it seems that it is impossible to force Mongoose to read off from secondary or primary. I asked author at Google groups, we'll see.
My Mongoose version is 4.2.4

Comment: Have you tried explicitly define each of the replica set hosts in the connection string? I'll dig in deeper.

Comment: I didn't try that. But is it possible to give at query level ?

Comment: According to the specification, it is possible to do it both Schema and model level.

Comment: Can you tell me if this syntax is right or not at query level